# Website (w3wp) High Memory Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I got an asp.net application that seems to be leaking lot of memory and the memory usage of W3WP continues to grow until AppPool recycles. I did the memory profiling, improved some part of code but it still having same problem.

I am bit confused about the memory management in an ASP.NET website, is it always the problem with code or some settings in IIS!

To check that I created a new server with a new asp.net website with only one default.aspx page (with some static text). Even than on every refresh of the page in browser the memory keeps increasing by about 200MB and more.

I did spend lot of time searching for the issue but can’t find any solution. Any ideas/help with getting to the bottom of this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: can you disable the memory recycle to see where is up to memory reach ? You can use the ProcessExplorer for that from sysinternals.

Comment: Provide details about customization that you did in web.config, global.asax and any third party components like elmah, log4net etc and add more details about what default.aspx does, how it accesses data from database etc

Comment: @Aristos, I checked the processExplorer by disabling the memory recycle, but the memory used on w3wp process still increasing.

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani, i kept the default web.config without any customization and no third party component. in the default.aspx got only one paragraph of text with no databse.

Comment: You may need to look for object that you not dispose.

Comment: @Aristos, so is it my code issue? please suggest me what i need to change in c# code.

Comment: @Ashutosh can you locate the one page that make the memory grow up ? Do you open and make images and forget to close and dispose them ? Do you open and close database and forgot to dispose them ? Do you keep in static memory large amount of data and forget to release them ?

Comment: @Aristos, I have created a new Website with default.aspx page nothing else (No Database connection, no image, no any content even). when i hosted on server i can see 1000K memory used on w3wp process. and i hit this  page 25 times i can see 25000K memory used on w3wp process.

Comment: @Ashutosh Then you have a serious problem. Some module or something similar to module makes this issue to you.

Comment: @Aristos, i configured it on my Laptop same memory increasing problem  with w3wp process. I am using .Net 2012 with IIS 7.5.

Comment: @Ashutosh You say that you have only one test page, can you show this code, upload the code what ever to see it ? I do not understand why that and you do not actually give any real informations to give an answer.